# Get content_type from Google Cloud file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have two api endpoints, one that takes a file from an http request and uploads it to a google cloud bucket using the python api, and another that downloads it again. in the first view, i get the file content type from the http request and upload it to the bucket,setting that metadata:

```
from google.cloud import storage
file_obj = request.FILES['file']
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path.join(
            path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__)),
            '..',
            'settings',
            'api-key.json'
          ))
bucket = client.get_bucket('storage-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob(filename)
blob.upload_from_string(
                file_text,
                content_type=file_obj.content_type
            )
```

Then in another view, I download the file:

```
        ...
        bucket = client.get_bucket('storage-bucket')
        blob = bucket.blob(filename)
        blob.download_to_filename(path)
```

How can I access the file metadata I set earlier (`content_type`) ? It's not available on the blob object anymore since a new one was instantiated, but it still holds the file.

Answer (score 7):

You should try

```
 blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
 blob.content_type
```